# Why Do I Get Unexpected " T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE Etc. On Short String?

Tags: javascript, php

I understand that there is probably something at play here that I am not aware of, but I cannot understand how I can be getting the following error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in F:\Software Development\****\HTDOCS\pages\home2.php on line 17
```

All six of the following lines throw that error when executed.  Their purpose is to output array values into a JavaScript.

```
echo "$title['{$line}'] = {$get['title']};";
echo "$content['{$line}'] = {$get['content']};";
echo "$islink['{$line}'] = {$get['islink']};";
echo "$linktext['{$line}'] = {$get['linktext']};";
echo "$linkurl['{$line}'] = {$get['linkurl']};";
echo "$path['{$line}'] = {$get['path']};";
```

The `$get` PHP array is storing a `mysqli_fetch_array()`.  I want to know what is causing the error above in my code, which only uses a single beginning and end quote, and how to prevent it.  I am aware that this could get flagged as a duplicate, as many questions on this topic have, but none in a fairly large sample those topics have been able to me.

Comment: You need `{$title[$line]}`.

Comment: you may also want to look into the php function `json_encode`

Comment: @JaredFarrish $title is not a PHP array, it is the name of an array I am creating in Javascript, which has the key value of the PHP variable $line.  Thanks for allowing me to clarify.

Comment: Then you want `"\$title['{$line}'] ...` Or `"\$title['$line'] ...` Double-quoted strings expand variables, so PHP is seeing `"$title ...` as a PHP variable, followed by what appears to be array syntax, hence the error.

Comment: Then you need to escape your variables (why would you prefix JS variables with `$` however?) in PHP double quoted string context, as in `"\$path['{$line}'] = ..."`

Comment: @JaredFarrish Precisely the answer I was looking for.  I never knew about double quotes messing with variables.  I recommend that you post this as the answer.

Comment: @BitFracture The only reason your code works (eg `{$line}`) is because double quotes are messing with variables ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want:

```
"\$title['{$line}'] ...
```

Or:

```
"\$title['$line'] ...
```

Double-quoted strings expand variables, so PHP is seeing `"$title ...` as a PHP variable, followed by what appears to be array syntax; it's a syntax error not to put array syntax with curly braces wrapped around in a double-quoted string, hence the error.

From the <kbd>manual</kbd>:

> The complex syntax can be recognised by the curly braces surrounding
>   the expression.
>
> If a dollar sign ($) is encountered, the parser will greedily take as
>   many tokens as possible to form a valid variable name. Enclose the
>   variable name in curly braces to explicitly specify the end of the
>   name.

Array references require the complex syntax.

See: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing